# Deserialize IEnumerable of protocol Buffer object sent by C# in C++

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers

I got a task that I got something like`IEnumerable<State> StateList;` sending from a C# based sever and I need to deserialize it in C++ based client. (`State` here is a proto class). I have no control on the proto. file so I can't just add any repeated message in the proto and make it work like a STL in C++. I don't know how I can deserialize this thing.

In C#,

`System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream (56 * stateList.Count());
ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, StateList);`

So I think it use protobuf-net and use this function

`public static void Serialize<T>(Stream destination, T instance);`

BTW, we use MQTT as our transmit protocol.

Comment: here's the documentation for protobuf c++ generated code
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated
Read that first, generate your c++ classes and ask again when you're stuck.

Comment: @RichardHodges Actually I have already have the State proto class in C++